# Deactivate Account not working

Tags: php, html, session, mysqli

The code in deactivate_myaccount.php ran once then thereafter it has an error at the top - "Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\includes\header-inc.php on line 2" . Also, this code is supposed to change the 'closed' field in the DB to yes so the person cannot log in, however that doesn't happen. I believe the sessions are playing up. When i re-log in with the same details the system allows me to log in and then when i select the 'deactivate account' button, it just says "You must be logged in to view this page!" and doesnt display the form for me to deactivate.

```
Deactivate_myaccount.php
    <?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
       header("Location: sign_up.php");
    } else {
          $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
    }


    include ("includes/header-inc.php");

    ?>

    <h2> Deactivate Account: </h2>

    <?php
    //Taking the user back
    $email = "";
    if ($email) {
        if(isset($_POST['no'])){
            header ("Location: includes/profile_student.php");
            }
    if (isset($_POST['yes'])){
        $deactivate_acc = mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET closed = 'yes' WHERE email = '$email'");
        echo "You account has now been deactivated! Sorry to see you leaving MYASTONSPACE";
        session_destroy();
    }
    }
    else {

        die ("You must be logged in to view this page!");   

        }

    ?>

<br/>



     <center>
        <form action="deactivate_myaccount.php" method = "POST" >
        Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? <br>
        <input type="submit" name = "no" value="No">
        <input type="submit" name = "yes" value="Yes">
        </form>
        </center>

<?php
include ("includes/footer-inc.php")
?>
```

profile_student.php

```
     <?php
        session_start();
        if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
           header("Location: sign_up.php");
        } else {
              $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
        }
        include ("includes/connect.php");
        ?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Profile</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/profile_student.css">

</head>

<body>

<div class="logo" style="margin-left: 750px;"><a href="Index.html"><img class="logo" src="images/logo.png"/></a></div>
<li><a href="/includes/logout.php">Log Out</a></li>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div class = "main_menu_buttons"  style="margin-left: 25px;">
                    <p> Home | Undergraduate Information | Post-Grad Information | International Students | Contact Us  </p>





     <div class = "User_options">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                         Personal information  
                        <br>
                        Favourite Properties
                        <br>
                         Upload Picture:
                        <br>
                         Messages 
                        <br>
                         <a href="includes/deactivate_myaccount.php"> Deactivate Account </a>
                  </td>
             </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, you have a call to `session_start()` in your includes/header-inc.php file. When you execute Deactivate_myaccount.php, this opens a new session and then includes the header. Because a session is already open, header-inc.php can't open it again and so this function call is ignored.

This is merely a notice and the cause should be fixed to comply with common coding styles, but it shouldn't affect the function of your application. I see someone else already helped you with the functional problem though.

Comment: How do i make this code so that when someone deactivates, the email that they logged in with changes to yes in the closed field on the DB? I believe something is wrong with the query and the 'if ($username) { section.

Comment: You need to insert the email address into the query. In the current version, $email is always an empty string and so you update all records without an email address instead of the record corresponding to your logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

If your email is always `$email = ''`, and it's not matching anything, it's just doing an update:

```
UPDATE users SET closed = 'yes' WHERE email = ''
```

which may or may not update the relevant user.

If you decide to populate that ... please escape it; or use PDO / parameterised queries.

Comment: How do i make this code so that when someone deactivates, the email that they logged in with changes to yes in the closed field on the DB? I believe something is wrong with the query and the 'if ($username) { section